Pumping Lemma does not disprove this language is regular
Using the alphabet $\Sigma = \{b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_n\}$ which consists of $n \geq 5$ symbols, prove that
$$
L = \{ w \mid \text{there are at least two different symbols } b_x, b_y \in \Sigma \text{ such that } b_x \neq b_y \text{ do not appear in } w \}
$$
is a regular language.
Show L is not regular
Proof by Contradiction:
Assume(for contradiction) that L is regular.
Choose: $$w = b_1b_2...b_{n-2}b_1b_2...b_{n-2} = xy^iz$$
Problem with pumping:

Pumping $y$: Since $|y| > 0$, $y $ must consist of symbols from the first $n-2$ symbols. Pumping  $y$ would not introduce the missing symbols $b_{n-1}$ and $b_n$.

Maybe it is a regular language? How would I show this?

Have you tried designing a DFA that recognizes $L$?

@Kai tried yes, but successful, no. It seems to have too much states, I would like a more straight forward way of attempting this question.

What can you recollect about operations between regular languages?

After greybeard's comment I tried, with regular expressions. For $1≤i<j≤n$ set
$$L_{i,j}= (b_1+b_2+…+b_{i−1}+b_{i+1}+…+b_{j−1}+b_{j+1}+…+b_n)^∗$$
that is, $L_{i,j}$ is the language of all strings over the alphabet $\Sigma\setminus\{b_i,b_j\}$ of $n−2$ letters. Being generated by a regular expression it is regular. Next observe that $L$ can be expressed as the union of all those $L_{i,j}$​:
$$L=⋃_{1≤i<j≤n}​L_{i,j}$$
There are $\binom n2$ pairs $(i,j)$ with $1≤i<j≤n$. Regular languages are closed under finite union. We conclude that $L$ is also regular.

IMO, the language is regular. You just construct a DFA with $2^{|\Sigma|}$ states, labeled by all subsets of $\Sigma$. All subsets whose cardinal number $|\Sigma|, |\Sigma|-1$ are non-final and the other are final.
The transition function:$$\text{$\delta(Q,x)=Q\cup x$, for $Q\subseteq \Sigma$.}$$
The initial state is $\emptyset$.

And the initial state is $\emptyset$!
